# MMS: Replacing pybitmessage with I2P tunnels

Tags: i2p, multisig, mms

Conceptually speaking, is it possible to replace [pybitmessage](https://github.com/Bitmessage/PyBitmessage) requirement in [Monero Multisig System](https://github.com/Bitmessage/PyBitmessage)  in favor of an I2P tunnel ?

If not, what additionnal feature(s) does pybitmessage provides over an I2P tunnel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I2P conceptually could be used instead of PyBitmessage. That was even part of the original MMS [thinking](https://web.getmonero.org/es/resources/user-guides/multisig-messaging-system.html):

> Hopefully a future MMS will build on Monero's "native" private communication system, Kovri, but we are probably still quite some time away from a Kovri release ready for broad use.

Kovri (abandoned, and essentially replaced by [i2p-zero](https://github.com/i2p-zero/i2p-zero)), is merely an I2P router implementation. Thus MMS could certainly be updated to make it work with i2p-zero, or some other secure messaging implementation. I suspect that had i2p-zero existed back when MMS was first designed, the author probably would never have bothered using PyBitmessage.